# C# opening a Form out of a TrayIcon

Tags: c#

i just used this snippet for creating a tray application with two buttons (settings and exit):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using WindowsFormsApplication1;

//*****************************************************************************
abstract class NotIco
{
private static NotifyIcon notico;

//==========================================================================
public static void Main(string[] astrArg)
{
    ContextMenu cm;
    MenuItem miCurr;

    cm = new ContextMenu();

    miCurr = new MenuItem();
    miCurr.Index = 0;
    miCurr.Text = "&Settings";
    miCurr.Click += new System.EventHandler(SettingsClick);
    cm.MenuItems.Add(miCurr);

    miCurr = new MenuItem();
    miCurr.Index = 1;
    miCurr.Text = "Beenden";
    miCurr.Click += new System.EventHandler(ExitClick);
    cm.MenuItems.Add(miCurr);

    notico = new NotifyIcon();
    notico.Icon = new Icon("tanss.ico");
    notico.Text = "TANSS Busylight Connector";
    notico.Visible = true;
    notico.ContextMenu = cm;
    notico.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(NotifyIconDoubleClick);

    Application.Run();




}

//==========================================================================
protected static void ExitClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notico.Dispose();
    Application.Exit();
}

//==========================================================================
protected static void SettingsClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>

    // This should open the "Settings"-Popup, containing 3 textboxes and a button to      save them to xml.

}

//==========================================================================
protected static void NotifyIconDoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}

}
```

Now i want to open a new Form as a Popup containing 3 textboxes to write some values in and a button to save them.

In the background, a never ending loop is requesting a url and parsing a value out of a json.

could you help me opening the new form (its not made yet, i just need it to open first :/)

and where do i embedd my background loop-code?

thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to open a new form by clicking the "settings"-button. thats the simple question :)

Comment: So create a new form and show it? Why include all this unrelated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
MyForm form1 = new MyForm();
form1.Show();
```

You have to create a new form object and show it on screen.

and, if you want to, you can set all others properties

```
form1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
form1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
form1.MaximizeBox = true;
form1.ControlBox = true;
......
```

I think is better (easier actually) to create the form from the designer and avoid the creation of every textbox and everything from code.